# npm ERR! C:\Users\mithlesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-19T05_00_01_126Z-debug.log

Tags: npm, react-router-dom

i am trying to run react-router-dom but getting this error. understand me to this error mean and give to solve of this error
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mithlesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-19T05_00_01_126Z-debug.log

````
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mithlesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-19T05_00_01_126Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Run `react-router-dom`, or you are trying to install that package as a dependency? Can you clarify and also update question to the CLI command used?

Comment: I have installed react-router-dom v6 and npm create app. when write npm start in terminal. Terminal show me this error which is given above if is possible to send screenshot of error

Comment: "npm create app", do you mean `npx create-react-app <app-name>`? Did you `cd` into the new app directory and run `npm install` *then* `npm start`?

Comment: I had tried to install and uninstalled this method which you said. Having tried that's show same error 